# Processing big text files that can take long hours (100+)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, nginx, delayed-job, resque

I am struggling recent days with the optimal way to process big CSV files.

The original idea was to process these big files with using **Delayed jobs**. But there's a problem that for jobs lasting more than 4 hours is better to not use **Delayed Jobs** but rather to use a single computer for doing that.

So, I wanted to use a single server for this - but here's another problem - there's a timeout limit of 30 seconds on nginx (is there any way to completely turn if off?).

Another way could be to use Resque - I've not been working with it, but it seems to be very similar to **Delayed jobs**.

So at the moment, I see as the best way to use our staging server, where I'd turn off the unicorn timeout (how to do that?) and I'll keep running there scripts a few days for processing all the CSV files.

Is there any better way to approach this thing?

Thank you

Comment: you should not wait hours until HTTP request is being processed, put the job in background and return HTTP response back "the job is in processing now..."

Comment: Also choose the efficient algorithms to solve the task, make it parallel and manage efficient manner. Avoid algorigthms with quadratic+ execution time.

Comment: Yes, just checking the parallel computing.

Comment: What is the nature of source files? Do they tend to be big and can not be split by certain kind like date range or certain type of key?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to process the entire csv as one gulp?  If not then set it up so that you send over rows of the csv file, and process to some intermediate model.  Have the main server feed the rows in, and the processing server keep working a few rows at a time.

If the result is going to a browser the "main server" can be the browser that sits there feeding to the main server.

Answer (score -1):

Put your delayed job processing on another server.  After you queue the job from the web server, render a page to the user telling them they will get an email when the processing is complete.  Include the user's email address in the object you enqueue to DJ, so you can do that when processing finishes on the job server.  You can set the DJ timeout on the job server to anything you want.

Comment: This method is outlined above. There's not known, how much time will be needed to process all data in the CSV file. It can be 80 hours or 200 hours. But that's just an estimate.

Comment: Set the timeout to 1000 hours then.  As someone pointed out in your almost duplicate post, you want a timeout just in case.  The email is a good solution for an indeterminate processing time.  Thanks for the downvote - just trying to help.  Good luck.